# cambiar texto en columna dataframe

Tags: r, bucle-for, condiciones, rstudio, dataframe

Estoy intentado cambiar en un dataframe una palabra 'Fire' a mayúscula y 'Grass' a minúscula pero me cambiar la columna entera, me podríais ayudar?

```
    for (i in df$Type1) {
  if(i == 'Fire'){
    df$Type1 = toupper(i)
  }else if(i == 'Grass')
    df$Type1 = tolower(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar lo que deseas puedes utilizar las operaciones vectorizadas en R. Es decir no es necesario que uses el `for`. Una solución seria:

```
df$Type1[df$Type1=='Fire']<-'FIRE'
df$Type1[df$Type1=='Grass']<-'grass'
```

Comment: También se podría hacer con un `for`. Lo que pasa en tu ejemplo es que dentro del `for` estas sustituyendo toda la columna `df$Type1`. Si notas en mi sol. uso corchetes para segmentar. Puedes leer más sobre esto en [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html)

Comment: Gracias! Justo eran los corchetes lo que me estaba faltando

Comment: @Ancre, no olvides aceptar esta respuesta si solucionó tu inquietud. Saludos.